# How to know the count of null values on a specific column?

Tags: sql, db2

I am having an error message saying that my select clause is not specified in a GROUP BY. But my other, somewhat similar, line of statements/conditions seems fine without it.

-- How many rows has empty middle initial?

```
SELECT workDept, COUNT(midInit)
FROM emp
WHERE midInit IS NULL
ORDER BY workDept;
```

Comment: Try count(*) instead of count(midInit). Count(colName) counts the non-null values.

Comment: Simply put: every expression outside aggregation functions in the `SELECT` clause must be in the `GROUP BY` list. The `workDept` expression violates this rule. This is what the [SQL0119N](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=messages-sql0000-sql0249#sql0119n) error description talks about.

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this work? This adds a GROUP BY to sum for each dept, and provides a count for all rows, as well as a count for when the midInit is null.

```
SELECT workDept, 
count(*) as allEmps,
SUM(CASE WHEN midInit is null THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as countNulls
FROM emp
GROUP BY workDept
ORDER BY workDept;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT workDept
     , COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY workDept) 
       - COUNT(midInit) OVER (PARTITION BY workDept) AS cnt_not_mid
FROM emp
ORDER BY workDept;
```

I added a total counter